502 error with devtools::check_mac_release
I'm working on testing an R package in development, and have always used R Mac Builder as one test environment.  However, today upon calling devtools::check_mac_release(), I get this error:
> devtools::check_mac_release()
Building macOS version of jagshelper (0.2.4)
ℹ Using https://mac.r-project.org/macbuilder/submit.html.
── R CMD build ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔  checking for file 'C:\Users\mbtyers\Documents\Current Projects\jagshelper/DESCRIPTION'
─  preparing 'jagshelper':
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  installing the package to build vignettes
✔  creating vignettes (6.5s)
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
─  building 'jagshelper_0.2.4.tar.gz'
   
Error in devtools::check_mac_release() : 
  Bad Gateway (HTTP 502). Failed to Uploading package.

Does the Bad Gateway (HTTP 502) mean R Mac Builder is down, or is there something wrong on my end?

Looks like a server fault. I just tested with a package version that is safely on CRAN and hot the same 502
